# How set kartik gridview Filter input In Footer?

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I'm trying to use kartik grid view and for some reasons need change filter inputs of every node from header to footer.

In http://demos.krajee.com/grid-demo there is a configuration to change the position of filter input from the header to the footer, but I can't understand how it possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this In your grid

```
'filterPosition'=>'footer', 
'showFooter'=>true,
```